# gradle build failed due to the server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3) PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run gradle build for my project with gradle version 6.9 and zulu 11 but it fails with below error :

```
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Auth-mapper'.
   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download commons-codec-1.11.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11)
  > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar'.
     > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar'.
        > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
           > PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification 
path to requested target
```

I have imported the certificate for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in cacerts of zulu-11 folder but still this issue is coming up.Also I am setting below properties in gradle.properties :

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

cacerts I copied to root folder of the project where build.gradle file is.

Comment: I am facing the same, how did you solve it?

Comment: you need to set the proxy settings for that.